# Unescaping string in PHP that was escaped in AS3

Tags: php, javascript, actionscript-3, utf-8

I have a problem. I have UTF-8 strings that was escaped in AS3 by using `escape()` function. Now I want unescape them in PHP. The problem is that if I'm using `rawurldecode()` or `urldecode()` I get only common character unescaped like ./+[] etc. but not special Latin characters (in my case ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪŽ) - they are left encoded. So how do I correctly decode strings in PHP?

**EDIT**
This is also aplicable for JavaScript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to escape your strings when you send them to PHP. Flash with do that for you.

So, if they are already escaped and you can do anything about it, just unescape them before sending them using URLLoader.

You should have clean values on the PHP side.

Comment: The problem is that I have a database full of such entries that I have to convert back to normal text.

Comment: Send them all to flash, and back to php :p

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got a solution from my colleague and it solves this issue

```
html_entity_decode(preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;", urldecode($str)), null, 'UTF-8');
```